# SMB not working Windows 8/10

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, nas, samba, smb

I've been tearing my hair out trying to connect to an SMB share and I keep getting "Unexpected Network Error" and "Error 0x80004005". I've tried enabling SMBv1 in Windows Features, and I've tried ensuring that sharing is enabled on the network. It is a Linux-based NAS server that is kinda old but I don't have the details on it. I can connect to it via my MBP (macOS Mojave), so this is confusing me.

Does anyone know how I can connect to this server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the solution to my particular case required a modification to the registry, but a relatively easy and benign change that is easily reversible.

Open `regedit.exe` and go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters` and do the following:

**Warning**: You should take a backup of the entire registry, or at least take a screenshot of this page to ensure you can revert any changes.

- Change `RequireSecuritySignature` from `0` to `1`. That isn't a typo; I know, this is really counter-intuitive, but it worked.

Other systems in our org needed these changes:

- Change `AllowInsecureGuestAuth` from `0` to `1`.
- Add `RequireSecureNegotiate` and set it to `0` (DWORD).

Then everything worked.